# Accented letters in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

How do I make accented letters in Ubuntu 20.04?  I had it before in previous versions, with one key that you first pushed to start making the accent.   I would like to have that same system again, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for so called "dead keys". Those are keys that don't print a character (on the first try), but influence *the next character*. For example, if you press `'`, it doesn't have an immediate effect, the key seems "dead". But if you press `e` directly afterward, you get `é`.

In Ubuntu, you can change the keyboard layout you want to use. Some layouts include dead keys, others don't. So if you want to use dead keys, just choose a keyboard layout that supports them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I have found for this is to install `GNOME Tweaks` and perhaps set the right <kbd>Windows</kbd> key as the <kbd>Compose</kbd> key.

`GNOME Tweaks` can be downloaded from the ubuntu software center.

[image]

That done, you will have a whole range of vowels and consonants you can use as special characters.

The `Compose` key latches, that is to say that the key appears to do nothing on the initial press in a sequence but the second key press will create the chosen character.

So, using this arrangement and an English (UK) keyboard, I am able to produce French and German accented characters such as `Compose` key then <kbd>e</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> in sequence to produce é or `Compose` key then <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> to produce ½. `Compose` key then <kbd>u</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> will produce the German umlauted ü and so on.

Some characters however are available without the need for the `Compose` key such as (if keyboard so equipped) <kbd>AltGr</kbd> <kbd>z</kbd> or <kbd>x</kbd> pressed together to produce « and » respectively or <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> for the  € symbol.

There are many other combinations and all it takes is a little experimentation to find the ones you want/need.

Comment: It's actually a lot simpler, like in the other answer.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I'd disagree with that. Changing keyboard layouts for just this purpose may open a whole different crock of unwanted issues.

Comment: No, not really, and what issues are you thinking about? Windows by default enables the "dead keys" layout variant whenever the input or system language needs accentuated characters, Linux distros give users options but invariably users want "dead keys" anyway for their language.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The `Compose` key is effectively a dead key.. that's the point. I don't use Windoze and the OP might not either. His question was "where to find the same system as he had before" and my answer addresses that. We will just have to agree to disagree. I have used the method described since v18.04 and in 20.04 so know it works well.

Comment: Indeed, but the tradition since typewriters were a thing is accent first followed by the letter. Choosing a "with dead keys" variant gives you that automatically. OTOH your method requires activating a special feature, changes the order any non-English speaker is used to type (and has been taught to do). Your method is fine for the occasional character and if you like it by all means... It is NOT what Spanish, French, Portuguese, etc. etc. expect.

Comment: And yes, I understand you don't understand what I'm saying due to not being the target audience and we'll have to agree to disagree. My vote has been cast.

Comment: It's a question of choices. The OP is in the happy position where there are two responses to his question and he can decide which applies best to meet his requirements. If he so wishes [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) the appropriate one or act as he wishes.

Comment: I got it wörking.  :)    Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nastyhorsefork Great! Which method worked for you?